# How to disable content when sidebar is opened?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

In Semantic UI library exists [sidebar](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar). But in the tutorial, I see only examples where sidebar doesn't disable content after opening. How can I perform this?

Comment: You need to be a little more elaborate on your question.

Comment: if we look here in simple semantic  https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html#/examples  in chapter "Using a custom context" there sidebar opens and creates gray layer on page content and disables it. is possible to do so in semantic-react?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `<Sidebar.Pusher>` content inside a disabled Dimmer like this:

```
<Sidebar.Pusher>
  <Dimmer disabled dimmed={this.state.sidebarIsVisible} as={Segment} >
   .... Your Segment content
  </Dimmer>
</Sidebar.Pusher>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dimmer)